# Making C/C++ eclipse working

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I do use to work in Eclipse cause i find it pretty good, but every day i am encountering this problem..."**'Cleaning all projects has encountered a problem'. Errors occured during the build.**" when I hit the "clean projects" button. I have win 7 64 bit.

The only solution for this issue to work is to restart my computer. But I don't find it that good, because even if I restart my computer in the next 5 minutes when I compile a certain program it gets stuck again, it shows the same annoying message.

Please give me a solution to make this work. I wouldn't like to switch to visual studio...

Comment: Are there more specific error messages in the current project's build output windows?

Comment: another message shown near the console to the problems tab is :
"cannot open output file Working.exe: Permission denied"

Comment: well, no one can help me ?

Comment: I would suggest you to learn how to use a command-line builder like `make` and a good editor (e.g. `emacs`). You might not need Eclipse, and it looks like it is bothering you. So don't use it.

Comment: The `in use` error is a sign that the executable program file is currently running.  Are you sure the debugger / running program is closed?  You could always try NetBeans instead of Eclipse.  I prefer that IDE over Eclipse for C++.

Comment: i am using the latest eclipse luna (ide c/c++) with the compiler mingw gnu 4.7.0. version... i can't believe no one is telling me something to get over this shit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure, but your application might have some unreleased resources which 'clean' command can't remove. Did executable process terminate? If not, you whould have this error. You could try to remove binaries from build folder manually and see what file causes and error.